# Manipulating large dataset with dcast

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, dcast

Apologies if this is a repeat question but I could not find the specific answer I am looking for. I have a dataframe with counts of different species caught on a given trip. A simplified example with 5 trips and 4 species is below:

```
trip = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5)
species = c("a","b","c","b","d","a","b","c","d","c","c","d")
count = c(5,7,3,1,8,10,1,4,3,1,2,10)

dat = cbind.data.frame(trip, species, count)
dat

> dat
   trip species count
1     1       a     5
2     1       b     7
3     1       c     3
4     2       b     1
5     2       d     8
6     3       a    10
7     3       b     1
8     3       c     4
9     3       d     3
10    4       c     1
11    5       c     2
12    5       d    10
```

I am only interested in the counts of species b for each trip. So I want to manipulate this data frame so I end up with one that looks like this:

```
trip2 = c(1,2,3,4,5)
species2 = c("b","b","b","b","b")
count2 = c(7,1,1,0,0)

dat2 = cbind.data.frame(trip2, species2, count2)
dat2

> dat2
  trip2 species2 count2
1     1        b      7
2     2        b      1
3     3        b      1
4     4        b      0
5     5        b      0
```

I want to keep all trips, including trips where species b was not observed. So I can't just subset the data by species b. I know I can cast the data so species are the columns and then just remove the columns for the other species like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
test = dcast(dat, trip ~ species, value.var = "count", fun.aggregate = sum)
test

> test
  trip  a b c  d
1    1  5 7 3  0
2    2  0 1 0  8
3    3 10 1 4  3
4    4  0 0 1  0
5    5  0 0 2 10
```

However, my real dataset has several hundred species caught on thousands of trips, and if I try to cast that many species to columns R  chokes. There are way too many columns. Is there a way to specify in dcast that I only want to cast species b? Or is there another way to do this that doesn't require casting the data? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach which I suspect will be very fast for you:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
result <- dat[,.(species = "b", count = sum(.SD[species == "b",count])),by = trip]
result
   trip species count
1:    1       b     7
2:    2       b     1
3:    3       b     1
4:    4       b     0
5:    5       b     0
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much. Still took several minutes to run but it worked perfectly. And such a simple solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat  %>%
   filter(species == 'b') %>% 
   group_by(trip, species) %>%
   summarise(count = sum(count)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   complete(trip = unique(dat$trip), fill = list(species = 'b', count = 0))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   trip species count
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1     1 b           7
#2     2 b           1
#3     3 b           1
#4     4 b           0
#5     5 b           0
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, good to know there is a tidyverse method too. However, when I try with my actual data the resulting table has NAs instead of zeros for the trips where my species was not caught. Perhaps an issue with the class of the variables...?

Comment: @FishMasterB. I used `fill` in complete to change NA to 0